# What (*) hides behind itself in this code

Tags: sql, postgresql

I don't get why when I SELECT pizzeria_name and person_name in FROM nested query it doesn't work but when I put `(*)` instead i see two columns displayed on the screen with names person_name and pizzeria_name. How can i substitute `(*)` to see the same result?

```
SELECT ( SELECT person.name FROM person WHERE person.id = pv.person_id ) AS person_name,
       ( SELECT pizzeria.name FROM pizzeria WHERE pizzeria.id = pv.pizzeria_id ) AS pizzeria_name 
FROM ( 
  SELECT *
  FROM person_visits
  WHERE visit_date BETWEEN '2022-01-07' AND '2022-01-09' 
) AS pv 
ORDER BY person_name ASC, pizzeria_name DESC;
```

I tried everything pizzeria.id, pv.pizzeria_id etc but it doesn't work

Any types of Joins are prohibited

That's how my table is looks like
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaWVB.png

Comment: Hard to say without knowing how your tables look like

Comment: Why all these sub queries? Looks like you could get the same result by using a simple and straight forward join

Comment: It's confusing what you are trying to do, can you add clarity with some example data, as consumable *text*.

Comment: I added a picture of the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the subqueries and use a plain query:

```sql
select
  person.name as person_name,
  pizzeria.name as pizzeria_name
from person_visits
join person on person.id = person_visits.person_id
join pizzeria on pizzeria.id = person_visits.pizzeria_id
where visit_date between '2022-01-07' AND '2022-01-09' 
order by 1, 2 desc
```

Standard naming convention of columns has been assumed.

---

If you absolutely must use subqueries:

```sql
select
  (
    select person.name
    from person
    where person.id = person_visits.person_id
  ) as person_name,
  (
    select pizzeria.name
    from pizzeria
    where pizzeria.id = person_visits.pizzeria_id
  ) as pizzeria_name
from person_visits
where visit_date between '2022-01-07' AND '2022-01-09' 
order by 1, 2 desc
```

Comment: That's looks good but I cant use joins according by a task rules

Comment: @Evgeny see edit to answer that doesn't use joins.

Comment: That's  a good one. Thank You!

Comment: @EvgenyStep: the second query is still using joins, just not by using the JOIN operator.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
 I agree but still not direct use of joins is allowed in the task and I found what was behind the (*) operator. According to my question it's - person_id and pizzeria_id so the question can be closed by now

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ( SELECT person.name FROM person WHERE person.id = pv.person_id ) AS person_name,
       ( SELECT pizzeria.name FROM pizzeria WHERE pizzeria.id = pv.pizzeria_id ) AS pizzeria_name 
FROM ( 
  SELECT person_id, pizzeria_id
  FROM person_visits
  WHERE visit_date BETWEEN '2022-01-07' AND '2022-01-09' 
) AS pv 
ORDER BY person_name ASC, pizzeria_name DESC;
```

Comment: person_id, pizzeria_id is hiding behind the (*) operator